# Overriding an event stops signal/slot from triggering

Tags: python, pyqt5

why overriding `keyPressEvent()` in QPlainTextEdit,
`self.clientDataEdit.keyPressEvent = self.clientKeyPressEvent`

stops the signal `textChanged()` in `QPlainTextEdit` from triggering

The `clientKeyPressEvent()` method triggers when keys are pressed but `QPlainTextEdit` stopped updating and `textChanged()` signal stopped triggering.

If required, I can try posting code but maybe this is something 'simple'

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer:

Because they are removing the default behavior, and one of them was to emit that signal.

## Long Answer:

Do not modify the methods by doing `foo.bar = baz` especially in the Qt bindings since they keep a cache of the used methods that can cause you these problems.

If you want to modify the behavior of a method without losing the default behavior then create a class that inherits and calls super from the method:

```
class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        # TODO
```

In addition, Qt allows you to listen to the events without the need to override the methods using an event filter:

```py
class Helper(QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.widget is obj and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            print(event.key(), event.text())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

```
helper = Helper(self.clientDataEdit)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used QtDesigner for interface.  It's not possible or straight forward to inherit a class.   I couldn't find a way to import a custom class there too.  I'll try the filter idea.

Comment: @Artur The options are: 1. use the promotion OR 2. Use the eventfilter. The second option is the simplest.